# Htaccess and wordpress in subfolder

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

So I have my WordPress in a subfolder, /members/ 
and I have an .htaccess in the root folder with only these two lines:

```
DirectoryIndex /closed.html
ErrorDocument 404 /closed.html
```

When I go to mydomain.com/members/ it redirects to the closed.html page.

I would be very grateful for some help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `/members/.htaccess` add these lines on top to override directives set by parent `.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
DirectoryIndex index.php
```